# Would working with a client outside work count as Conflict of Interest

Tags: professionalism, freelancing, clients, conflict-of-interest

I was wondering that I have discovered a potential client that is currently looking for similar services to the one my organization currently provides. I can provide them the same services my organization provides on a freelance basis since they are out of the city from where my organization operates from however I am worried of it would constitute a "conflict of interest" since the client can easily contact my company directly and since I would be working on a freelance basis I would be forced to use organizations similarly to my employed organization so I am confused if I would breaching my contract with them or breaking the trust of the organization.

Comment: What does your contract or employee handbook state about conflict of interests?

Comment: It states that any employee working for other parties without the consent and knowledge of the organization is considered as a conflict of interest

Comment: @Farina5126 that seems pretty clear, doesn't it?

Comment: @Farina5126 bingo! there is your answer

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question? If the policy is that this would be considered a conflict of interest, and you knew that, why did you post the question? Or did you not know the policy before asking?

Answer (score 10):

> I am worried of it would constitute a "conflict of interest" since the
> client can easily contact my company directly and since I would be
> working on a freelance basis I would be forced to use organizations
> similarly to my employed organization so I am confused if I would
> breaching my contract with them or breaking the trust of the
> organization.

Providing the same services that your employer provides is almost certainly a conflict of interest, and might also be a breach of contract.

Read your contract.

> It states that any employee working for other parties without the
> consent and knowledge of the organization is considered as a conflict
> of interest

That seems pretty clear to me. Your organization has to consent. I'm assuming they have not yet been told, and thus have not consented.

Thus, it would be a conflict of interest at this point in time.

You could ask your employer for their permission, and see if they would consent.

Comment: And if you aren't comfortable asking your employer, then there's your answer

Comment: Yep.. this is about as slam-dunk a case of CoI as I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

> Would working with a client outside work count as Conflict of Interest

Based on what you stated is in your contract/employee handbook:

> It states that any employee working for other parties without the consent and knowledge of the organization is considered as a conflict of interest

You would need to let your employer know about your plans and they would have to agree to it.  I doubt they will be thrilled about your attempt to take away a potential client.

Answer (score 0):

You may already be in the danger zone.

If you used any company resources: phone, computer or email, to establish that contact, the company may be entitled to any of the business you negotiate with that potential customer.

If this is the case, it would go beyond asking permission, they may be concerned that you are using company resources to steal potential business from them. Your job could be in danger.

Answer (score -4):

Just because something is stated in an employee handbook doesn't make it the truth, or legally binding.  The language you have provided to us is quite broad.  Effectively what it means is that you're not allowed to have any other sources of income outside of your job at the same time. I am not an attorney, but I would tell you that most US courts would consider the clause as unconscionable.  "We own you"... nah.

Such a situation presents a conundrum to the average worker.  Your company's not going to give you the raise you need to cover growing expenses (like the recent inflation of 30-40% in the US), but also won't *consent* (see that?) to you taking a side job.  Or the company cuts your hours in half.

Unless your company has an established relationship with this potential client already OR you are sharing information about your company's processes, organizational structure, or internal workings, there's no conflict. The key element in asserting a conflict is that there's some tangible damage to the company's income or reputation. If I were you, I would just go about making my money and keep my mouth shut. Again, I am not an attorney, and this does not constitute legal advice.

Comment: I don't understand what the bit about presenting a conundrum has to do with the answer. How does that effect whether it's legally binding or not?